# Domain filter to view child_id in Many2one filed

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-10

Is there a way to use domain filter on Many2one filed such that only the current user_id and the child of that user id(if any) could be visible.

Comment: you can use domain in python as well xml.

Comment: Yes bro, I currently use domain as below

<field name="lot_id" options="{'no_create_edit': True}" domain="[('product_id','=', product_id)]" context="{'default_product_id': product_id}"/>

I want add domain filter such that... only the current user and his parent user(Mangaer/Admin) should be able to see. I need help on that.

Comment: Mean you want to set access rights ?